# MATLAB - complex line/path integral

Tags: matlab, octave, numerical-integration

I'm trying to find complex line/path integrals over a few circular closed paths using the integral command. My code for the integral of 1/(z-i)^2 over the circle {z:|z|=2} traversed once anticlockwise is as follows:

```
fun = @(z) 1 ./((z-1i) .^ 2);;
g = @(t) 2 .*(cos(t) + 1i .* sin(t));
gprime = @(t) 2 .*(-sin(t) + 1i .* cos(t));
q1 = integral(@(t) fun(g(t)) .* gprime(t),0,2 .* pi)
```

(I would expect the answer to be 0 and matlab gives 6.6613*10^(-16)-4.4409*10^(-16)i).

My code for the integral of e^z/(z(z^2-9)) over the circle {z:|z-2|=3} traversed once anticlockwise is as follows:

```
fun = @(z) exp(z) ./(z .* (z.^2-9));
g = @(t) 2+3 .*(cos(t) + 1i .* sin(t));
gprime = @(t) 2+3 .*(-sin(t) + 1i .* cos(t));
q1 = integral(@(t) fun(g(t)) .* gprime(t),0,2 .* pi)
```

(I would expect the answer to be pi/9(e^3-2)i, but matlab gives 5.4351+6.3130i).

As can be seen above, my problem is that while the code gives accurate values when the circular path is centred at the origin, it fails otherwise; sometimes giving an accurate imaginary part but inaccurate real part or just a completely inaccurate answer.

Can anyone see what is going wrong?

Comment: For your first question : $6.6613*10^(-16)-4.4409*10^(-16)i).$ is numerically identical to 0 !!!The best proof is the connection with the smallest number representable by Matlab which is $eps = 2.2204e-16$... Notice that the number above is $3 eps - 2 eps i$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have answered to the first question in a comment.

For the second question, you have made an error in the computation of the derivative : additive constant 2 should disappear. In this way the result you will obtain is 6.3130i, in full compliance with the theoretical value.

```
fun = @(z) exp(z) ./(z .* (z.^2-9));
g = @(t) 2+3 .*(cos(t) + 1i .* sin(t));
gprime = @(t) 3 .*(-sin(t) + 1i .* cos(t));
q1 = integral(@(t) fun(g(t)) .* gprime(t),0,2 .* pi)
```

I take the opportunity to advise you, instead of the previous method, to compute complex integrals by **"way points" method** 
(see for example https://uk.mathworks.com/help/matlab/math/complex-line-integrals.html) ; here, it would be

```
C=[-2+i,-2-i,5-i,5+i];
integral(@(z) (exp(z) ./(z .* (z.^2-9))),1,1,'WayPoints',C)
```

where C is a square (more generaly any square) enclosing the desired poles and only them. (always take the second and third parameters to be 1,1)

Appendix : Rapid personal check of the theoretical value by residue theorem :

2i pi(Res(f,0)+Res(f,3))=2i pi(1/(-9)+e^3/(27-9)).

Answer (score 0):

The answer you are expecting for the second problem is incorrect. Mathematica tells me that the answer should be:

```
pi*(2/45)*(5 + (exp(2))*(5*exp(1) - 9)) + (pi/9 *(exp(3) - 2))*i

= 5.435120011473026 + 6.313043326012592i
```

which is almost exactly the answer you get from Matlab.

Remember that the `integral` function in Matlab performs **numerical** integration, so the results you get will be subject to machine roundoff errors. This means that the result you got for the first problem is also essentially correct; it's probably the best answer you could get with numerical integration.